# I keep getting the "Matrix dimensions must agree." error no matter what I do

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, matlab-figure, equation

So I am trying to plot M as a function of sigma:
[image]

using this code in Matlab:

```
beta = 1;
alpha = -1 ; 
u = 0 ;
sigma = 0: 0.001 : 4;

M = (alpha + beta)./2 - ((beta - u)./2) .* erf(( beta - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)) ...
    + ((alpha - u)./2).* erf(( alpha - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)) ...
    -(sigma ./(sqrt(2.*pi))) .* [ exp( -(( beta - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)).^2) ...
    -exp( -(( alpha - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)).^2 ) ] ; 

plot(sigma,M)
```

but no matter what I try and change, I keep getting the "The Matrix dimensions must agree" without stating which part of the code is the problem.

Comment: Be careful when using square brackets, in MATLAB they are used to define vectors! I assume MATLAB interprets `[ exp( -(( beta - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)).^2) ...
    -exp( -(( alpha - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)).^2 ) ]` as a 1x2 vector. You should use parenthesis instead

Comment: You should not write lines this long. Instead, compute smaller parts of the equation independently, then build up the final result but by bit. This makes it much easier to understand the code and to find errors.

Answer (score 1):

you are using square brackets instead of using normal parenthesis causing misdimensioning, also the output of that equation is all zeros.

```
beta = 1;
alpha = -1 ; 
u = 0 ;
sigma = 0: 0.001 : 4;

M = (alpha + beta)./2 - ((beta - u)./2) .* erf(( beta - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)) ...
    + ((alpha - u)./2).* erf(( alpha - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)) ...
    -(sigma ./(sqrt(2.*pi))) .* ( exp( -(( beta - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)).^2) ...
    -exp( -(( alpha - u)./(sqrt(2).*sigma)).^2 ) ) ; 

plot(sigma,M)
```